# Aplication Error, Code=H14 "No web processes running", path="/favicon.ico"

Tags: django, git, heroku, deployment, favicon

Heroku returns me this message when i try open the app

> **Application error**
> *An error occurred in the application and your page could not be served. If you are the application owner, check your logs for details. You can do this from the Heroku CLI with the command
> heroku logs --tail*

the error is:

```
2020-06-23T20: 04: 27.882267 + 00: 00 heroku [router]: at=error code=H14 desc="No se están ejecutando procesos web" método=GET ruta="/favicon.ico" host =proyectojoao.herokuapp.com request_id=852edcba-a708-41ec-90e4-306366cf68d3 fwd="104.33. 31.5 " dyno= connect=  service= estatus=503 bytes= protocol=https
```

I tried scale dynos, but this return:

```
Couldn't find that process type (web)
```

And i have the Procfile archive in the root of my project whit:

```
web: gunicorn blog.wsgi --log-file -
```